# Unsupported grant type exception on Flurl POST

Tags: c#, flurl

I am making a POST to a client authentication endpoint with an encoded auth header and I receive
Unsupported grant type exception. Speaking with the client, they say that the request Body should be 'raw' as it appears in POSTMAN. How to set such attribute in Flurl? The same request returns 200 in POSTMAN but 401, Unsupported grant type exception in Flurl.

```
var bodyText = @"grant_type=password&username=hi@api.com&password=123456A";
   var encodedAuthHeaderText = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{secret}"));
            var response = await Post<ResponseAuth>(bodyText, tokenEndPoint, $"Basic {encodedClientIdSecret}",
                cancellationToken);


   private async Task<T> Post<T>(string bodyText, string resourceEndPoint, string encodedAuthHeaderText,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = default(T);
            try
            {
                response = await $"{_baseEndPoint}{resourceEndPoint}"
                    .WithHeader("Authorization", encodedAuthHeaderText)
                    .WithHeader("Accept", "*/*")
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .WithHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .PostJsonAsync(bodyText, cancellationToken).ReceiveJson<T>();
            }
            catch (FlurlHttpException fe)
            {
                var error = await fe.GetResponseJsonAsync();
                if (fe.StatusCode != null)
                    throw new CounterPartyIppQuoteException((HttpStatusCode) fe.StatusCode, fe,
                        $"Error encountered when making a POST request to {resourceEndPoint} with auth header to IPP");
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide details about what `encodedAuthHeaderText` is? The full header value needs to include the [auth scheme and a space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) before the credentials part.

Comment: Hi Todd, its the base64string in the format below,          var encodedClientIdSecret = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{secret}"));

Comment: So, the format is Basic {{BASE64_ID}}

Comment: ok, so `encodedAuthHeaderText` INCLUDES the literal string "Basic "? I suggest editing your question to include the code that builds `encodedAuthHeaderText` given a hypothetical username and password. I think that's key to solving this.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the value of encodedAuthHeaderText

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're calling `PostJsonAsync`. That's telling Flurl to JSON-encode the body, and since you're passing a string instead of an object, it's probably just putting quotes around it, which you don't want. You've specified the Content-Type and formatted the body exactly how you want, so use Flurl's `PostStringAsync` instead of `PostJsonAsync` and I think it should work.

As a side-note, you could have used a couple Flurl shortcuts here, namely `WithBasicAuth` (instead of your first `WithHeader`), which just takes a username & password and does the encoding for you and adds the header, and `PostUrlEncodedAsync` which produces that `bodyText` for you based on a cleaner C# object, and sets the Content-Type header for you. See the [docs](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/) for examples of both.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've tried almost the whole of morning but no luck. Eventually the service vendor came up saying it always worked for python clients. Then, just to try out I wrote a node script and it came up with an error "self signed certificate in certificate chain". Then I added this line process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0; and I've managed to receive a response with a warning, Warning:"Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling cert verification." I need to do this in C# and Flurl

Comment: When calling paypal, using "PostUrlEncodedAsync" for the "grant_type" was the solution